# googlemap's api becomes disabled sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im using googlemap with javascript,

i have enabled every google maps's service, and i got the api key from browser
, set the http referers as "abc.com" and "abc.com/*". 
Then i set the src as src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abc&sensor=false"

everything was working in the first hour, then i become unpredictable..
sometimes, it work, sometimes, it doesn't work, and an error alert appears “Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.”

```
however, after i refresh the page, i will work again..
```

this make my website becomes so unprofessional, someone plz give me a solution!!  thank you

regards

Comment: Have you exceeded API usage limits?

Comment: thx xlm for ur response, i considered if this is the answer, however, i only clicked it for less than 15 times today, and im not sure Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day > 15, ~ ~

Comment: There are multiple reports lately about api key problems. I suspect something is wrong at google with api key authentication.

Comment: no idea, i see some website using google maps, they have no problem like this, so i suppose its my problem.. i should call google for help tomorrow

Comment: How's this following up for you? I had/have exactly the same problem (it seems to have disappeared for now, by itself, but I have to see if that sticks because it was quite random). I wrote [a bug report concerning this issue here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6756)

Comment: i didnt call them, but it's becoming better now... no error for these days