# Different errors (quota, disabled, bad API key, or none) when loading Google Maps API JavaScript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We ported our site to Google maps, but we get different errors when loading a map using the JavaScript Maps API (v3 of course). Other times the map loads correctly. The two most prominent errors are:

> "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the
>   Terms of Service for more information
>   http://www.google.com/intl/en_US/help/terms_maps.html." (JS Alert)

And:

> "This site has exceeded its daily quota for maps. If you are the
>   creator of this site, please visit the documentation to learn more."
>   (this is a DOM overlay)

**Live minimal example**: 
This code is not yet live but there's a minimal example here: http://mappat.com/maptest.php. It is simply Google's own Hello World example with our key filled in and even that gives problems.

**Network traffic inspection**: 
I noticed the first error is shown when 'AuthenticationService.Authenticate' fails (returns [0,5,0]), the second when 'QuotaService.recordEvent' returns [0,null,0]. These are remote calls from within the SDK and I don't know if these details are relevant.

**What we tried**: 
Billing is enabled by the way and we stay way below our quota limits. I tried a lot of things already, new key, waiting a  few days, turning the Maps API off and on again in the console, etc. I filled in the allowed referrers but also left it open to allow others. No difference.

I don't dare to start a new project in de dev console because this whole thing started when I did actually just that because I had (different) problems with the server-key. That server part is now working flawlessly btw, kind of ironically.

[**Edit**: I just tried to leave out the API key when loading the JS maps file, which, fingers crossed, seems to work. But now the server-side calls to places/searchtext start to give random "The provided API key is expired." errors, again (same reason we created the new project). Coincidence? Also, I don't like this option, especially with regards to the future (reaching 25k, going beyond and going Business Account)].

So, I'm stuck. Hence my first SO question ever. Could it be that we are blacklisted? Perhaps because of the duplicate project? Is there a way to find that out and/or to get us 'reset'? Or am I simply overlooking something?

Any help is appreciated because until we solve this, this is a deal-breaker.

**Sidenote**: I also filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6756&q=apitype%3aJavascript3%20type%3aDefect%20key&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars%20Project%20Apitype) because I think giving random errors on itself is not expected behaviour. It's up to the dev team to decide if they agree. If not, we still have a problem, hence this SO question.

Comment: That really curious. Can you try to create a new Console API project, with "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" enable, generate an API KEY and try with it ?
Can you also try tu put your domain as "Edit allowed referers" ?

Comment: @Seb: I'm a bit worried that creating yet another project for this website may put an even stronger 'doing things not as they are supposed to be done' label on our domain-name. Or am I getting 'paranoid' without a reason and shouldn't I worry about that?

Comment: What browser(s) are you encountering the problem with?  I don't see any issue with [your minimal example](http://mappat.com/maptest.php) in Chrome (but obviously haven't tested it as extensively as you have)

Comment: One other thought, perhaps use the [release (v=3) or frozen (v=3.15) version, rather than the experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), might have been an update being pushed while you were testing.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for thinking with us! I've tested mainly in Chrome (our target browser for now), but also in Safari and Firefox. On different computers and also in incognito mode. I get the error on the minimal example most of the times within 2-4 (*shift*) refreshes. If you really can't reproduce it, that would be a clue on itself. Btw I also already tried with v=3.

Comment: Just did 10 shift-F5's in a row without errors.  Do you have a firewall that might be causing issues?

Comment: @geocodezip That is very odd. I just did 10 refreshes and had only 4x a successful load, and 6x the first mentioned error. I have seen the error on 3 different networks on 2 different computers now, and my 2 colleagues (one in and one out of the office) did so as well. I'm thinking (because that would also explain the randomness I experience) this may be gmaps-server-related? They must load-balance based on geo-location (Amsterdam for us). Perhaps one or some servers have a bad (cached) config for our domain. Or something, I can only guess without knowing their infrastructure.

Comment: @Jochem maybe you said true about cached config of Google servers...
For now, the error has disappeared (on my side). Have you made some changes ? Well, sorry, she just respawn... I know that Google made lot of changes on their Console API. Once, for a project i've solved an issue by creating a new one because internally the old project has something bad in his configuration :/

Comment: I had a key problem since last week and reading your post I tried it again with my site and now the key is working which previously did not work. Either it's a caching issue and something gets stuck in google servers, or google's key validation implementation has problems and sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't. I wasn't over quota either.

Comment: If you search for it on google there were multiple reports of this disabled key problem recently.

Comment: @Tom thanks for sharing your experience. Let's hope it is a temporary thing because I am running out of things to try. I linked to the bug report at the bottom of my question. If it resembles your situation, you may want to star that or describe your experience there. (I did Google a lot but most reports of this error were due to using the server key in browser, wrong allowed referrers, Maps API being off or - less recently - v2/v3 transitions)

Comment: The reports I found are about using the browser keys and setting the allowed referers properly, yet the api throws the disabled error message. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952626/googlemaps-api-becomes-disabled-sometimes

Comment: Or this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/2383erWPHss

Comment: These are recent reports (May 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue magically disappeared after a week or so.

I didn't get any response from Google, but they may have change/reset something behind the scenes, of course. The bug is still marked 'new', by the way.

My advice to others having this issue is to first check some basic things, since the individual errors I got could also result from actual things you're doing wrong (ie mistake in allowed-referers). If all seems okay after triple checking, just remove the API key from the request, test along like that for a while and retry in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a syntax error in your php var dump:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYuWR5wqux1_iTmfIWPveheIOr5PhqjEs&?>sensor=FALSE&language=en">
</script>
```

you have **?>** just before sensor

Comment: Good point, this was something I just added for testing something else. Stupid of me to play with an example I posted on SO. Sorry. Fixed it, but that was not the problem.

Comment: Another issue (although it would give a different message) is that `sensor=FALSE` should be `sense=false`.

Comment: Well I tried both, it doesn't matter. If you're sure I'll change it to 'false' just to be complete.